# UIViewController before SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I use SWRevealViewController to implement sideBarMenu. It is all ok, it works fine.
But now I need to create a screen, before it. This is a loading screen where user can see how new data is loading to application from server. After loading completed, I call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showApp" sender:self];
```

This segue is going from my loading screen to SWRevealController, but it doesn't work. It just show my Loading controller.

Comment: the segue doesn't work?

Comment: no, it does show my LoadingController. Nothing happened after [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showApp" sender:self];

Comment: then the app is stuck on the loading screen? are you calling perpareForSegue?

Comment: Yes, it just stucked on loading screen. perpareForSegue works, but there no changes on screen

Comment: you sure you've copied the segue identifier correctly? (happened to me a few times..)

Answer (score 0):

You should set segue class SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController